# ASP.NET MVC vs. Webforms: Replacing WebForms Controls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have read several other posts here, so i get the idea on the pro vs. cons, especially having full control over the rendered html code etc. (in MVC).

My question is regarding the UI controls: In MVC, i will have to write all UI controls myself (or the html equivalent). Now is that not going to be very difficult?
The reason why these 3rd party vendors for asp.net are there is just because of the fact that it is difficult to write UI controls for ASP.NET all by ourselves, and be able to target to all web browsers, and also that we are better off concentrating our time on the business logic rather than spending the whole lot of time writing the UI controls HTML code ourselves.

I understand that this feature gets us the full control over the final html, but is it not counter-productive to do this UI bit ourselves. If it was so easy to write them ourselves, how come these 3-rd party vendors are all living now. We could have done this all by ourselves all these years of WebForms days.

I am sure i am missing something here or being a little stupid, but please enlighten me as to what i am missing in specific regard to the UI bit being written by ourselves.

Just because i get full control over the program by writing in IL code, do we go and do that? We still use C# and things like that - So that theory of "having full control over html" - i am not bought into that idea.

Please help in getting my head around this UI bit.
Other things i understand, about the separation of concern, TDD based development possible with MVC etc.
But why would i go around writing the UI controls all by myself - it is a bit a work isn't it?

Comment: I apologise if my post is a duplicate. if you can point me to aother post on this exact point (on the UI bit i am concerned with), i would even try and delete this post from here. Thanks.

Comment: Sombody had commented a few seconds back that my post was a duplicate, and i replied to it as a comment, but that other person has apparently removed their comments now :-)

Comment: I was that somebody. Re-read that post and must admit that it's not an exact duplicate. Anyway - i'm sick of this "ASP.NET MVC vs WebForms" thing. It's getting even worse than "PHP vs RoR". :D

Comment: Apologies to have spolied your mood with this debate topic, but nobody around me at work could explain the exact bit i was asking about, and most of teh answers where that the UI will all come from something called HtmlHelper class so i should not worry about it at all.

But that did not give me enough answers since i took a look into it, and it was not helping me with any UI controls i wanted in my pages :-), so i thought i will post my quetion here.

I am not intending to compare, since i do research allways before asking questions, but this one was very difficult to get the answer for.

Comment: Damn... you are too nice to keep up my bad mood.

Comment: Cheers :-) Thanks for reading up my post.

Comment: @Arnis: Read so far and wanted to reply to your comment: I'm really waiting to read the answers because this is exactly the issue I don't understand: How do you program and especially how do you get third party components in ASP.NET MVC. Obviously, there must be a solution. So the OP's question is exactly great for me!

Comment: @Avi strange thing is - You don't actually need super smart "do-everything" components. it's that never-ending story about re-usability. once You get efficient with html+css+js, it becomes easier to write Your own stuff than trying to understand how to re-use and configure complex controllers. do learn asp.net mvc if You haven't done that yet.

Comment: @Arnis: Will do, will do. However, me thinks will also learn Telerik controls very fast. Say I want to use a Calendar, or an Editor (as I surely want to do in the first site I'm going to worki on to help my son study Geometry). How would I do this without controls?

Comment: @Avi calendar is a good example when You should re-use something existing. I would go with lightweight javascript library. don't know what You mean with `Editor`.

Answer (score 11):

The thing is:

**If you want to master in web development you have to master HTML + CSS + Javascript**

And with WebForms you have to learn the WebForms way to do it, but with MVC you have the power of .Net with the freedom to generate the HTML + CSS + Javascript you want.

Comment: Eduardo, the same power (to generate your HTML) you have with WebForms also.

Comment: asp.net controls are leaky abstractions that hide just enough complexity to make simple applications easy, but when you need to do more than they offer you end up facing a very steep learning curve.

Comment: That's a nuclear weapon for drag&drop developers. Lack of knowledge asks questions about tag soup and going back to classic ASP not inappropriate technology.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a new rant on the subject http://www.charliedigital.com/PermaLink,guid,6dcb0333-9d70-40c7-975b-0ff4011c4661.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Problem is, ASP.NET MVC is much younger product than ASP.NET. For many years 3rd party companies have been developing TONS of reusable components, and I believe that it is only a matter of time before comparable set of controls will be available for ASP.NET MVC.

If you really need very rich GUI with 3rd party controls, and you can't rewrite them in acceptable time - stick with asp.net. Altough in my opinion, MVC gives you tons of power it wouldn't be wise to spend much more time rewriting controls than you can save. If you can live without controls, and like MVC concepts - use MVC, and you'll most certainly see 3rd party solutions as soon as they'll there is growing market (maybe thay've already noticed that, I don't know) for mvc extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the UI and the user experience are vital to the success of a web app. Making the page intuitive and easy to use, minimizing the amount of navigation the user has to do to get the job done, and providing effective feedback and interactivity can make all the difference between a site that users want to use and one that they avoid.

If you are trying to attract users on a public website, a pleasing appearance and excellent usability are key to building repeat visits.

If you are writing an intranet app to be used by hundreds or thousands of employees all day long -- as I mostly do -- making the UI efficient and easy to use really means a lot to your users.

So, I wouldn't downplay the importance of the UI. It isn't a nuisance. It's a key part of the user experience. I suggest that a web developer should embrace whatever tools and strategies that will get the job done. That often means coding the UI controls yourself. Or working with a teammate who likes doing that part of the work.

Answer (score 1):

I recently refactored a very complex website using ASP.NET + handworked javascript to MVC + jQuery.  The complexity of the code was reduced by 50%-75% and became much more testable.  I replaced all the complex webcontrols I had to write (with a steep learning curve I had to overcome) with very simple HtmlHelper methods.

Don't forget, when you use custom webcontrols, you are given a very static UI by the control developer.  With raw HTML, you can take advantage of styles and ui developed by the whole web industry.

Increased simplicity, decreased development time, testability, flexibility in UI... I don't want to go back.

Comment: You're given a static UI if that's how the control was written. There's no reason that the "styles and UI developed by the whole web industry" could not be encapsulated in a web control.

Comment: To understand what I'm talking about just look at how ASP.NET controls render side-by-side content and how everybody else does it.  Because control authors set the html in stone, you will find more often than not you can't easily use common layouts and styles; you have to work hard (e.g. control adapters) to adapt the styles to use with your web controls.

Comment: Will, WebForms allow you to create templatable WebControl (given the fact that you create ITemplate properties) wich gives the integrator the ability to write the very custom html he wants. The developer can build very a complexe set of web controls without writing a single line of html.

Comment: @Manitra who writes that templatable webcontrol?  How long does it take?  How much knowledge does it require?  To do something comparable is trivial in MVC.  IOW if you can get someone else to write it for you your coding time goes way down.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to remember that ASP.NET MVC is just the first release. I don't think there is intrinsically any reason why you couldn't have the equivalent of server controls to enable certain tasks - remember, there are many server controls that don't generate any mark-up (such as the Repeater, PlaceHolder, ListView). These type of controls could be useful in a future MVC setting, I think.

Comment: Sure - you will always be able to make/use controls as long as they don't use viewstate. But isn't that what makes them worthy and windows-forms-like in most cases?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that ASP.net came around when lots of developers were still used to doing desktop applications and just beginning web development.  AT that point in time abstracting the details of the web with controls and post backs was a great way to get people started.  At that point we weren't trying to perfect the web, we just wanted to get on it!

Now that the web has matured and we've all slowly learned about html, css, javascript and the likes we want to optimize our websites for our own needs and we don't want to depend on ASP.net Forms controls to control the fine details of our websites.

In summary, I think this is about the natural evolution of many developers from the desktop to the web

Comment: That's a good point. Developers are important and not technology they use.

Answer (score 1):

I for one, am very thankful that you cannot use ASP.NET controls in MVC.

Controls, as many have already pointed out, are just server side blocks of code that render HTML and javascript on your behalf.  Things like a datagrid are great, until someone asks you to make a slight modification, like having a delete confirmation alert, and then it seems impossible to do certain tasks.

The good news is that there are very powerful jQuery tools written to help you.  jQgrid is a great grid replacement that does WAY more than the ASP.NET grid...

http://www.trirand.com/blog/

jsTree is a treeview that is fantastic.  Again with the jQuery....

http://www.jstree.com/

And the truth is that most things you can do with razor, HTML, javascript and CSS.  It's so simple that it's just stupid.

It's hard for people like myself who were web forms developers to grasp MVC and why you should use it because it's so simple.  It's difficult to let go of the complexity of conventional ASP.NET.  But it feels so good when you do.

And don't mix web forms with MVC.  You can do it, but you will wish you hadn't.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the key thing that I think you are missing.  When ASP.NET is no longer the MS way of doing things...you will eventually be forced to move on and do something else.  I have programmed in perl, ASP classic, then ColdFusion, then PHP, then ASP.NET web forms, then ASP.NET MVC...the only thing that they all have in common is the underlying database, design patterns, best practices for a given set of technology AND...HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and Photoshop.

No one is asking you to learn MVC.  No one is telling you to not use WebForms.  However, complaining that you have to write a raw UI is not going to get you very far in this industry.  You should be learning something new every day...and it sounds like some time spent on HTML and CSS would be a great place to start your focus!

The biggest problem you have with relying on third party controls is when a client asks you to do something that the third party controls don't cover.  If you can't replicate their complexity plus the added feature request on your own you are skirting a possible failure in your professional livelihood!  You will need to know how to do it all...eventually!

I generally suggest that you embrace new technologies.  You don't have to use them...but you should at least know how.  This way you will know what the best tool is for any given project.

Comment: Sure, thanks. I am prepared to learn HTML + CSS + JS with support from JQuery, JQ UI :-)
Just thought i will ask to confirm that "it is going to be me" who will write the UI code, just in case i missed some point there ;-)... i don;t wnat to end up looking like a fool in my team when others would say " are you crazy? Why are you writing all that yourself you idiot?" :-)

Just wanted to get clarified there, and avoid such a situation.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually - quite often small kick with client code can do a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I've been wondering - what's an equivalent of 'control' from webforms in asp.net mvc? It's not a partial view for sure. What else it can be? Controller + partial views via partial requests?

Maybe i'm dumb, blind or both, but i haven't seen any 'control' for asp.net mvc. Just a lot of code snippets to accomplish one specific thing or another.

I believe that asp.net mvc is quite unfriendly with rapid development. Only way out of this problem - a lot of open source code (like MvcContrib), tutorials, sample applications & most important - slightly smarter developers.

Comment: We don't really need "slightly smarter" developers.  We just need the developers of ole that knew how to do things in notepad instead of requireing a bunch of fancy widgetry and tool sets!  Notepad forces you to know your profession...not just think you know your profession.  If you are a web developer...and you cant work in raw html, javascript, css, etc. then you aren't really a web developer just yet.  You are really still just a script kiddy with a dependancy on dreamweaver or visual studio.  No worries...we all started out there!  I know I did!

Comment: Call them whatever you like. The idea remains.

Comment: @Andrew: i started out in notepad, html, css, javascript, classic asp. and moved onto webforms. Do i really want to go back to notepad? No thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to replace Webforms controls with something else from MVC. Just mix them - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx

Comment: Yeah, but there aren't any controls in MVC. Can't deny that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was also wondering how to use 3rd party controls in ASP.NET MVC. Obviously, and contrary to some answers here, it had to be possible.

As much time has passed since the question was asked, the industry has evolved. So I've searched and found (but havent' yet tested) solutions such as [Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx) .

I'm posting this answer here mainly to support other MVC newbees such as myself - Just Google

> "asp.net mvc" controls